# MSSQL Automated Jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have been recently reading about configuring jobs within SQL Server and that they can be configured to do specific tasks.

I recently had issues whereby all the DB indexes where > 75% fragmented and I wondered if there was a way to have SQL Server automatically manage itself.

Now when reading about setting up and configuring jobs it mentions the `SQL Server Agent`.
In the DB Server I was looking at the `SQL Server Agent` was switched off.

This made me think that having a "job" to handle the rebuilding/reorganising of indexes may not be great if this agent can simply be disabled...

Is there anything at a DB level which can be configured to do this, or is this still really in the hands of a "DBA"?

So to summarise, my question is, what is the best way to handle rebuilding/reorganising indexes?

Comment: It often makes a difference if you say what SQL Server version you are on... and typically, you would add it as another Tag on this question.

Comment: Not knowing your version, this may or may not be exactly what you see, in Management Studio, when you (1) connect to a server as a database engine, (2) expand the servername, (3) expand "Management", (4) right-click "Maintenance Plans" and (5) select "New Maintenance Plan", to create a "Maintenance Plan", but this blog entry has some great introductory tips:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windchillonsql/archive/2010/05/12/sql-server-maintenance-sequence.aspx

Comment: FYI, creating a Maintenance Plan will automatically generate jobs, for the SQL Server Job Agent to execute.  The maintenance plan wizard lets you choose whether your steps will show separately or together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A job calling [some stored procedure](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)s could be your answer.

Automation of this task depends on your DB: volume of data, fragmentation degree, batch updates, etc.

I recommend you [to check regularly your index fragmentation](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/scripts/tsql/index-usability-tunning-strategy-performance), before applying an automatized solution.

Also, you can programmatically check if [SQL Server Agent is running](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/check-sql-server-agent-is-running).

Comment: What if I am not "in control" of the SQL Server itself but rather just the database. would I be able to add jobs to SQL Server Agent?
Is SQL Server Agent a required component of SQL Server, could a customer not have SQL Server Agent installed, etc. ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run with a car without wheels, but it's a little bit more difficult. As a general idea from my experience, try to influence your sponsors/stakeholder by transforming your technical problem in a money problem :).